# Questions about makefile

Tags: makefile

Here is an easy makefile.

I have 2 questions.

1. all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
   Why put the SOURCE in the dependency.
2. ".cpp.o:"
   Why not write ".o: .cpp"

   ```
   CC=g++

   CFLAGS=-c -Wall

   LDFLAGS=

   SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp

   OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

   EXECUTABLE=hello


   all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

   $(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 

       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

   .cpp.o:

       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
   ```

Comment: If the SOURCE is not included as a dependency - then running "make all" after having modified a source file would result in the executable not being recompiled.

Comment: the .cpp.o: is an old-style suffix rule indicating that a file with a .cpp file extension can be turned into a .o version of the file by running the subsequent command(s). There is more in-depth information about GNU make OLD-FASHIONED SUFFIX rules at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency of `all` on `$(SOURCES)` is not necessary or even useful.  The dependency information should be such that the executable depends on the object files, and the object files depend on the source files.

The notation:

```
.cpp.o:
```

was the way the original (7th Edition UNIX™) version of `make` handled compilation rules.  GNU Make (and Sun Make) used the `%` notation to allow:

```
%.o: %.cpp
```

Basically, it was a design decision that made sense at the time and maybe less sense in retrospect.  It was not the most egregious problem (that would be tabs at the start of command lines).

Comment: What's the problem with tabs, other than that people new to make sometimes forget them?

Comment: Almost everywhere else is agnostic about the content of white space.  What's more, it actually doesn't provide much of a useful service, AFAICT.  The parser for a `makefile` is not any harder if you allow arbitrary white space at the start of command lines.  So, it creates an obstacle for users (especially beginner users) which is really not necessary.